# R: If field is not null, add next two rows of specific column to total

Tags: r, grouping

I was originally trying to do this in Teradata SQL, but I realized that I also have R at my disposal.  I feel like there may be a more universal answer in R.

```
ID          TOTAL          QTY 
111         NULL           100  
112         NULL           150  
113         312.00         70  
114         NULL           200 
115         14.00          40 
116         NULL           70  
117         NULL           100  
118         NULL           170
```

In the data above, I want to create a new column called THREEDAY.  If TOTAL is null, then I want THREEDAY to equal the amount in QTY.  If TOTAL is not null, however, I want TOTAL to equal the amount in QTY **plus** the amount in QTY for the following two rows.  For example:

```
ID          TOTAL          QTY          THREEDAY
111         NULL           100          100
112         NULL           150          150
113         312.00         70           310
114         NULL           200          200
115         14.00          40           210
116         NULL           70           70
117         NULL           100          100
118         NULL           170          170
```

For ID 113, the amount in THREEDAY is 310 (70+200+40), and for ID 115, the amount is 210 (40+70+100).  For the rest of the IDs, the amount in THREEDAY equals QTY because the value in TOTAL is missing.

My skills are not up to par to tackle this kind of problem, so any assistance would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a string as `"NULL"`.  Please show the dput of the example

Comment: NULL isn't a string...just missing.  I guess it would be "NA" in R syntax.

Comment: assigning threeday[i] to ifelse(is.na(dataframe[i,2]),dataframe[i,3] , dataframe[i,3]+dataframe[i+1,3]+dataframe[i+2,3]) within a for loop ought to work, though probably it can be vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` methods for this.  As the OP commented that the "NULL" would be `NA` in `R`, get a numeric index for non-NA elements in 'TOTAL' ('i1'), create the 'THREEDAY' column as the copy of 'QTY', loop over 'i1', subset the elements in 'QTY' for the sequence from that index to the next two index, get the `sum` and assign those values to the 'THREEDAY' for the 'i1' position.

```
i1 <- which(!is.na(df1$TOTAL))
df1$THREEDAY <- df1$QTY
df1$THREEDAY[i1] <- sapply(i1, function(i) sum(df1$QTY[i:(pmin(nrow(df1), (i+2)))]))
df1
#   ID TOTAL QTY THREEDAY
#1 111    NA 100      100
#2 112    NA 150      150
#3 113   312  70      310
#4 114    NA 200      200
#5 115    14  40      210
#6 116    NA  70       70
#7 117    NA 100      100
#8 118    NA 170      170
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 111:118, TOTAL = c(NA, NA, 312, NA, 14, NA, 
NA, NA), QTY = c(100L, 150L, 70L, 200L, 40L, 70L, 100L, 170L)), 
 .Names = c("ID", 
"TOTAL", "QTY"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```